# Using Firebase Push Notifications with WordPress siteand Xamarin app

Tags: wordpress, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently looking for a WordPress plugin which is compatible with Firebase Cloud messaging. I'm trying to create a Xamarin app and want to pull data from a WordPress site. Firebase is now recommended over Google cloud Messaging, however I can't seem to find any plugins that are compatible with it?

Does anyone know any they would recommend for this?

Appreciate the help you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the "next" version of GCM...

For `Xamarin.Android` there is a beta Nuget currently available:

```
<package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" version="32.4.0-beta2" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
```

Ref: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/29

For `Xamarin.iOS`:

No prebuilt Nugets available yet...

Google provides the iOS frameworks via CocoaPods and a downloadable `.zip`, I am using `Xamarin.iOS` Binding projects for Firebase on `Xamarin.iOS`.

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

For `Xamarin.Forms`:

No prebuilt Nugets available yet...

Comment: Thanks for the help @SushiHangover, One other question, will my Wordpress site work with firebase or will i need to look for a plugin?

Comment: @whiskeycoder Firebase has a JavaScript-based SDK/API, I do not know what you want parts of it you want to integrate to WordPress, but there are a number of WP Plugins that integrate Firebase, it just depends upon what you are looking for...